# Facing a peculiar behavior with regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text file in the below format

```
//*****
// Header comments 1
// Header comments 2
//*****

//=====
// Sub header 1 - comments 1
// Sub header 1 - comments 2
//=====
[Sub_heading1]
Info line 1
Info line 2
Info line n

//=====
// Sub header 2 - comments 1
; Sub header 2 - comments 2 (; indicates comments just like //)
//=====
[Sub_heading2]
Info line 1 //comment about info 
Info line 2
Info line n
```

*I want to write regular expressions that would return the following results to me:*

```
//=====
// Sub header 1 - comments 1
// Sub header 1 - comments 2
//=====
[Sub_heading1]
Info line 1
Info line 2
Info line n
```

&

```
//=====
// Sub header 2 - comments 1
; Sub header 2 - comments 2 (; indicates comments just like //)
//=====
[Sub_heading2]
Info line 1 //comment about info 
Info line 2
Info line n
```

I came up with the a few regular expressions. I'm posting the closest one & the issue with it.

**Regular expression:** `==+(.*?)//=+(.*?)//=`

**Issue:** Instead of 2 matches, it returns 3 matches.

**Match 1:**

```
====
// Sub header 1 - comments 1
// Sub header 1 - comments 2
//=====
[Sub_heading1]
Info line 1
Info line 2
Info line n

//=
```

**Match 2:**

```
====
// Sub header 2 - comments 1
; Sub header 2 - comments 2 (; indicates comments just like //)
//=====
[Sub_heading2]
Info line 1 //comment about info 
Info line 2
Info line n

//=
```

&
**Match3:** The entire contents of the file.

I'm aware that the matches that I got are slightly different from what it must be, but I can live with that.

**The problem is when it returns the entire file, my C# code runs into a deadlock & doesnt do anything. I also tried this on regular expression testers on the internet & it returned no results with an error stating the pattern maybe inefficient.**

*Edit 1 begin:* 
**C# Code:**

```
Regex regEx = new Regex(@"==+(.*?)//=+(.*?)//=", RegexOptions.Singleline);
var results = regEx.Matches(searhText); //searchText refers to the contents of the file as one string.
foreach (Match match in results)
Console.WriteLine(match.Value);//on the last match the code runs in a deadlock
```

*Edit 1 end:*

Could anyone point me at a better way to get around this? And also why this regex is returning the entire file contents as a match.

Comment: You do not get 3 matches. After running `Regex.Matches`, you get a collection of `Match` objects each containing 3 *groups* in it, 0th one is the whole match, the 1st one is the value inside Group 1 (captured with the pattern inside the first pair of unescaped parentheses) and Group 2. If the file is very large your regex is too inefficient, really. Just read line by line, check if a line starts with the delimiters and add only qualifying lines to the result.

Comment: I'm using RegEx.Matches since I want my results separately. Reason being I would perform further parsing on them.

Comment: Do not use regex for large files. You will have trouble loading them into memory. Read line by line and build the result "by hand".

Comment: Alright, do you know why my pattern is matching the entire file? That is starting from //**.. I'm torn on how that is being returned as a match.

Comment: Ankit, your current regex cannot match from `//**`. You have some issue with the code.

Comment: I missed on telling, I get the 3rd match in notepadd+, whereas in C# code it runs into a deadlock. My file has just under 3000 lines. Is that too large a number for a regex to work?

Comment: If you write a regex in a linear way, it is not a problem for a regex itself. But do you really want to use an "unreadable" (for you and most others) regex or a regular line-by-line parsing code that is way faster and makes sense to almost every programmer?

Comment: BTW, you did not post the code that fails for you.

Comment: I added the c# code now.

Comment: With this code, you can only get 1 match from the string above.

Comment: Wiktor, I got 3 matches. They are mentioned in the question above. The first 2 are understandable, but the 3rd one (which is the entire file contents), not sure how that got matched..

Comment: Perhaps, but it is not reproducible because your data is different from what you posted. Even the regex is not what you posted.

Comment: I agree the data is not the same as posted (but it follows the same pattern). Edited the regex

Comment: `=` matches a `=`, then `=+` matches 1 or more `=` chars - **there is no way to match `//**` at the start**.

Comment: Exactly, but while I perform this in Notepad++ its a match. And in C# it runs into a deadlock. Do u see any other way or regular expression that I can use for the aforementioned purpose?

Comment: You are pulling my leg, [there is one expected match in NPP](https://imgur.com/a/VI4o9), too.

Comment: Yes you are right, but in the file that I have which follows exactly the same pattern that I have described it shows one more result that expected. However, but in this example it works correctly.